# Display node links without hover action in script http://arborjs.org/

Tags: jquery, arbor.js

I'm using  http://arborjs.org script. When mouse pointed to one of the nodes, it shows links. But i need to display such links on one of the nodes just after script loads (without hovering any). How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to answer without any code, but if you're using the same code as the homepage:

- Set the node's alpha property to 1
- Don't set `shape:'dot'` if a node has sub-nodes you want to see